# How to find intersecting polygons and union them using geopandas?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

I have a geo dataframe with coordinates and I would like to check if polygons intersect with each other. If yes union these intersecting polygons.
How can I handle with geopandas?

```
 geom                                                  index
0  POLYGON ((68.19900 54.75696, 68.17856 54.75425...     6
1  POLYGON ((68.15779 54.83775, 68.15851 54.83540...     7
2  POLYGON ((68.13169 54.81037, 68.14262 54.80948...     8
3  POLYGON ((68.13895 54.82565, 68.13897 54.82237...     9
4  POLYGON ((68.19696 54.75934, 68.17838 54.75674...    10
5  POLYGON ((68.19454 54.84803, 68.19473 54.84899...     1
6  POLYGON ((68.03500 54.76356, 68.04866 54.75895...     2
7  POLYGON ((67.96892 54.78627, 67.97568 54.78423...     3
8  POLYGON ((68.01496 54.75251, 68.01477 54.74690...     4
9  POLYGON ((68.17951 54.86391, 68.17650 54.85733...     5
```

for example `index 6` intersects with `index 10` and `index 4` intersects with `index 2`. Further, I want to union 6 with 10 and 2 with 4. Finally, I will have 8 rows instead of 10.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a GeoDataFrame with multiple Polygons where `p1` and `p2` intersect:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
p1 = Point(1, 0).buffer(1)
p2 = Point(0, 0).buffer(1)
p3 = Point(0.5, 3).buffer(1)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(id=[1, 2, 3]), geometry=[p1, p2, p3])
```

Looks like that:

```
   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((2.00000 0.00000, 1.99518 -0.09802, 1...
1   2  POLYGON ((1.00000 0.00000, 0.99518 -0.09802, 0...
2   3  POLYGON ((1.50000 3.00000, 1.49518 2.90198, 1....
```

[image]

Then create a merged GeoDataFrame where all data is lost but every overlapping geometry is merged :

```
gdf_merge = gdf.dissolve().explode(index_parts=True)
```

Gives you this :

```
   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((0.47140 -0.88192, 0.38268 -0.92388, ...
1   1  POLYGON ((1.48079 2.80491, 1.45694 2.70972, 1....
```

[image]

And finally, join new simplified GeoDataFrame with old one to recover data. The duplicates are found by `AREA` attribute that is dropped later :

```
gdf_clean = gpd.sjoin(gdf_merge, gdf, how='inner', predicate='intersects')
gdf_clean['AREA'] = gdf_clean['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.area)
gdf_clean = gdf_clean.groupby('AREA')
gdf_clean = gdf_clean.agg({'geometry': 'first', 'id_right': 'min'})
gdf_clean['id'] = gdf_clean['id_right']
gdf_clean = gdf_clean[['id', 'geometry']].reset_index(level='AREA').drop(columns=['AREA'])
```

Ouputs:

```
   id                                           geometry
0   3  POLYGON ((1.48079 2.80491, 1.45694 2.70972, 1....
1   1  POLYGON ((0.47140 -0.88192, 0.38268 -0.92388, ...
```

[image]